# Reading string with spaces using scanf?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want the following to ask for input and then take in a string (with spaces), then do it again. But it repeatedly outputs "input$" after typing in the first string.

```
char command[80];

while(1)
    {
        printf("input$ ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", command);    
    }
```

My output: `nput$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$ input$^C`

What I want:

```
input$ hi
input$ this can take spaces
input$
```

Comment: You're better off just avoiding `scanf`.  http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: The trouble is that once you've read to the first newline, the next character is a newline, so the `scanf()` reports that it was not able to convert anything (return value 0, not EOF), but you're blithely ignoring it.  You have to read the newline (`getchar()`, perhaps) to allow it to continue.  Or add a `\n` after the `]`; or, indeed, a space would do.  If you don't care about leading spaces, a space before the `%` would work, too.  It is incredibly hard to use the `scanf()` functions correctly; it is really 'cruel and unusual punishment' to make beginners use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally want to use something like:

```
char command[80];

while(1)
{
    printf("input$ ");
    scanf("%79[^\n]%*c", command);
}
```

The '79' prevents a buffer overflow, and the `%*c` consumes the new-line from the input buffer. It has one minor shortcoming: it will still consume (and throw away) a character, even if the next character in the input buffer is *not* a new-line. If you have to deal with that possibility, you can read it and ignore it unless your `command` buffer is full:

```
char ignore;

scanf("%79[^\n]%c", command, &ignore);

if (strlen(command) == 79)
    // `ignore` probably shouldn't be ignored after all
```

Comment: +1 Perfect! @OP Check out the documentation for scanf (man scanf), it's worth the read -- it's a much more powerful function than you might think.

Comment: This has trouble when code 1) reads a line that begins with `'\n"` 2) as noted, consumes the 80th characters even if it is not a `'\n'` which could be prevented with `"%79[^\n]%*1[/n]"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
char command[80];

while(1)
{
    printf("input$ ");
    fgets(command, 80, stdin);    
}
```

Comment: I second Jerry. I think this is bad advice.

Comment: @Lucas: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used. Note that the updated answer (using `fgets`) is okay.