# Not able to accept white spaces in string in C

Tags: c, input, whitespace

I would be glad if I get help with this. I am not able to accept white space in a string. I am working on socket programming using C. I tried following things. Please help me.

1. `char name[100];
    fgets (name, 100, stdin);`

I tried using `fflush(stdin);` before fgets.

2. `fgets (name, 100, stdin);`
3. `scanf("%[^\n]s",name);`
   (Ref for 1,2&3: [Reading string from input with space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character))
4. `scanf("%[^\t]s",name);` worked for me but I have to press tab+enter after giving input. Because of which everything I input after the name is printing on next line at the server. I want to create table-like structure. How can I accept string input with white spaces? Thank you in advance

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_LINE 256

struct course{
  char name[100];
  char id[20];
  int registered;
  int empty;
  char time[20];
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    struct course c;
    FILE *fp;
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    char *host;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    int s, new_s,n;
    int len;
    int rec=1;
    char data[1000];
    int choice;
    char search[20], del[50];
    char add[1000]="\n";
    char avail[10],ocu[10],sem[10],id[10];


    if (argc==2) {
        host = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: simplex-talk host\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (!hp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplex-talk: unknown host: %s\n", host);
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: connect");
        close(s);
        exit(1);
    }


    do{
        printf("\n\n*************************************************\n");
        printf(" 1.List All \n 2.Search \n 3.Add \n 4.Delete \n 9.Quit \n");
        printf("\nPlease enter your choice: \n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);


        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1: send(s, &choice,sizeof(int), 0);
            printf("\n==============Requesting All Records..=======================\n");
            len = recv(s, &data,sizeof(data), 0);
            fputs(data,stdout);
            break;

        case 2: send(s, &choice,sizeof(int), 0);
            printf("\nPlease Enter Course Name/ID: ");
            scanf("%s",&search);
            send(s, &search,sizeof(search), 0);
            printf("\n======================Searching for The Record..================\n");
            len = recv(s, &data,sizeof(data), 0);
            fputs(data,stdout);
            break;

        case 3: send(s, &choice,sizeof(int), 0);
            printf("Press Tab And Enter After Entering Course Name...\n");
            printf("Please Enter Course ID: ");
            scanf("%s",&c.id);
            printf("Please Enter Course Name: ");
            scanf("%[^\t]s",&c.name);
            printf("No of Students Registered: ");
            scanf("%d",&c.registered);
            printf("No of Vacancies: ");
            scanf("%d",&c.empty);
            printf("Course Time: ");
            scanf("%s",&c.time);
            send(s, &c,sizeof(struct course), 0);
            printf("\nInserting New Record..\n");
            break;

        case 4: send(s, &choice,sizeof(int), 0);
            printf("Press Tab And Enter After Entering Course Name...\n");
            printf("Please Enter Course Name/ID To Drop: ");
            //scanf("%[^\t]s",&data);
            scanf("%100[^\n]", del);
            //fgets(del,sizeof(del),stdin);
            send(s, del,sizeof(del), 0);
            break;

         default: printf("Please enter valid choice...\n");
        }

    }while(choice!=0);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `fgets()`? all the other options are dangerous. And, `fflush(stdin)` is strictly *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It's not letting me enter the name.

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with [tag:sockets].

Comment: oh, okay. But fgets works fine with normal C program.

Comment: there should be no `s` in `scanf("%[^\n]s",name);`. Use [`scanf("%100[^\n]", name);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18371169/995714) or [`scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", name);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306465/995714)

Comment: "It's not letting me enter the name." is the result of prior un-posted code.  Post enough code that in itself shows the problem.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm not able to enter input if I use either of them.

Comment: @n.m. it did accept using gets now.. Thank you so much for this help...

Answer (score 0):

To trim whitespace from a string, loop through the string until [`isspace`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace) returns `false`. You can also trim the trailing whitespace by jumping to the end of the string with `strlen` and working backwards with `isspace`. In the example shown here, we trim any leading or trailing whitespace, and print the result.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    char buf[128];
    fgets(buf, 128, stdin);


    int start = 0;
    // remove any leading whitespace.
    while(isspace(buf[start])) start++;

    int end = strlen(buf);
    // find the first character from the end that is not whitespace
    while(end > start && isspace(buf[end - 1])) end--;

    buf[end] = '\0'; // terminate the string to trim the whitespace at the end.

    char * name = &buf[start];
    printf("Name = '%s'\n", name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code snippet. It works fine to remove whitespaces in a string. But, I want to remove whitespaces between the strings. As I am passing the structure, after giving ID, Name is appearing on the new line. Is there any way to remove such white space?

Comment: in the question you want to read a string with spaces. No where else you said that you want to remove whitespaces in that string

Comment: @Akshay C `\n` counts as whitespace, so the above function will also trim the trailing newline from your input, which you said was a problem at the server.

Comment: so if you input "My Name\n" (since `fgets` includes the enter), it will give back "My Name"

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Sorry for the confusion. I thought I can take care of this issue at the server side by removing the additional '\n'

Comment: @AkshayC That would work too, but what is your question then?

Comment: I was not able to do either of them.  I was not able to accept the input using fgets. But my problem got solved. I could able to accept the input with whitespaces using fgets after doing following thing:                    //fgets will not work after using scanf
//to get it work again, read the extra characters and discard
                char ch;
                  while((ch= getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
                fgets(c.name, 100, stdin);